# .htaccess from http and www to https non www

Tags: .htaccess

Of the four possible variations of my site URL, I would like to redirect to https://example.com (https:// non-www).

My .htaccess file contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This redirects from http:// to https:// but not from www to non-www

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your first rule generic like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Almost, but now it doesn't redirect a trailing slash to a non-trailing slash page? i.e. 'http://www.example.com/abc/' to 'https://example.com/abc'.

Comment: Sorry I didn't write that as it was already working, and I didn't see how the other changes could affect that. Your updated rules still don't redirect to a non-trailing slash version, but I will ask that question separately.